# sublayer with non-finite position [inf inf]

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9

I am using a third CocoaPods library written in Objective-C to take a screenshot of a UITextView. It was OK for iOS 8, but after I change the syntax for iOS 9 and Swift 2, it throws an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'sublayer with non-finite position [inf inf]'

Here is the code from the library:

```
- (UIImage *)screenshotForCroppingRect:(CGRect)croppingRect
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(croppingRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    // Create a graphics context and translate it the view we want to crop so
    // that even in grabbing (0,0), that origin point now represents the actual
    // cropping origin desired:
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (context == NULL) return nil;

    NSLog(@"hiii :%f" , croppingRect.size.width);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -croppingRect.origin.x, -croppingRect.origin.y);

    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenshotImage;
}
```

The problem is this line:

```
[self.layer renderInContext:context];
```

I realize this is because I am trying to take a snapshot of the UIView which contain a UIScrollView. If I remove the UIScrollView subview, the error is gone.

So what does this mean?

> sublayer with non-finite position [inf inf]

Anyone having the same issue and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I solved this:

Following this post

https://github.com/facebook/ios-snapshot-test-case/issues/112

the error is coming from the library I used, so do a search on all the files and find out

```
CGRectNull
```

and change them all to

```
CGRectZero
```

That resolved the problem.

Comment: I could hardly believe it but that fixed it :D looks like someone at apple used == a bit too often ;)