# Capturing screenshot leads to 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'sublayer with non-finite position [nan nan]' crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, screenshot, calayer

I'm capturing a screenshot of my application like so:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
shareImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(shareImage);
[data writeToFile:@"Screenshot.png" atomically:YES];
```

The issue is, 9 out of 10 times the app crashes with:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'sublayer with non-finite position
>   [nan nan]'

Obviously there is a division by 0 happening somewhere, but I'm unable to figure out why this is occurring.

This is a legacy project, no ARC, no auto-layout, and this crash only occurs on iOS 9.0 and above. What could be causing this?

Comment: I think this error occurs because the layer which is executed has frame in this form:
Layer frame == {{inf, inf}, {0, 0}}

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P what could cause the layer to have this frame?

Comment: I think a check with CGRectIsNull and check for CGRectIsInfinite should help here. Probably the changed the implementation of the rendering.  check the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823407/calayerinvalidgeometry-crash-on-ios9-sublayer-with-non-finite-position-inf-inf